# Port 8090 seems closed even though it's open

Tags: networking, iptables, firewall, ufw, jenkins

I installed Jenkins on port 8090, tried disabling ufw and doing `ufw allow 8090`.
`yougetsignal.com` is still showing that port as closed, and trying to open the jenkins webapp results in a timeout error.

`java      3284         jenkins  118u  IPv6  34046      0t0  TCP *:8090 (LISTEN)`

Jenkins is running and listening to that port, what could be blocking it?

Comment: If you're behind NAT, you're going to have to set up port forwarding, DMZ, or something similar at your router to access from outside of your network.

Comment: Is there anyway you could try accessing from inside your local network to verify that the issue is at your computer and not at your router?